# Llamar a metodo cada cierto tiempo ionic wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ionic, angular, ionic3

traigo noticias desde un wordpress, pero quiero poder actualizar las noticias cada cierto tiempo, y seria llamando al constructor que trae las noticias.. muestro el codigo.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
export const WORDPRESS_URL = 'http://despertadorlavalle.com.ar/';
export const WORDPRESS_REST_API_URL = WORDPRESS_URL + 'wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=817';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class WordpressProvider {
  constructor(public http: Http) {
  }
  getRecentPosts(page:number = 1){
    return this.http.get(
      WORDPRESS_REST_API_URL)
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Comment: Aldo, si has encontrado una solución, es mejor que la pongas como respuesta y no como comentario

Comment: No he encontrando ninguna solucion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias cosas que me llaman la atención: Parece que no tienes un `service`, sino que el `controller` llama directamente al servidor para obtener los datos. No es una buena práctica.

Por otro lado, si estás trabajando con Ionic 3, la versión de Angular debería ser al menos la 4.3, con lo que deberías poder usar `HttpClient` en lugar de `Http`  para hacer las llamadas AJAX.

Para terminar, si quieres crear una llamada que se haga de manera reiterada, puedes hacer algo como:

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';

const TIME_INTERVAL = 30000; // milliseconds

// ...  en el método:
return timer(0, this.TIME_INTERVAL).switchMap(
    () => this.http.get(this.api_url ).map(res => res.json());
```

Este código hace una llamada GET al instante y luego la repite cada 30 segundos.

Comment: Hola pablo, tengo un service, que se le llama provider ahora verdad?.Este se llama wordpress.ts y es el que me retorna el json.. te respondo con el codigo que tengo, lo quiero actualizar no cada cierto tiempo, si no actualizarlo con doRefresh por que estoy utilizando tabs que es otra cosa..

Comment: Un provider es algo disntinto a un service

Comment: Hola Pablo, algun medio para conversar por mensaje privado, asi me explicas como mejorar la pregunta, y dejar en claro lo que necesito? Gracias por la gran ayuda que estas haciendo.

Comment: Puedes entrar al chat de SOes: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: Creo que no me deja, por que necesito mas puntos..

Comment: Algun otro medio, para comunicarse?